# Moving horizontal (landscape) figure to the right

Tags: floats, landscape

I want to move these horizontal figures using the landscape package to the right side, since I have a lot of space left. I have tried to do it unsuccessfully.

[image: Bolivia Oil Timeline H]

[image: Bolivia Political Timeline 1 H]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape, rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
     \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 74, width=24cm, scale=0.5]{"Bolivia Political Timeline 1 H".png} \hspace*{4cm} 
    \label{fig: Bolivia Politics 1}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}   [H]
  \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 74, width=24cm, scale=0.5] {"Bolivia Oil Timeline 1 H".png}  \hspace*{4cm}
    \caption{Petroleum Sector in Bolivia under Evo Morales}
    \label{fig: Bolivia Petroleum}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [p] will center, [t] will be left and [b] will be right, although anything may be converted to [p] if it is too large.  Friends don't let friends use [H].

Answer (score 0):

- Your images are are unknown to us, so here are replaced by `example-image-duck`, which is provided by LaTeX.
- Default size of text area is smaller than size of your image, so images protrude out of it.
- Option for image appearing `trim=0 0 0 74, width=24cm, scale=0.5` doesn't make any sense. Considered is the last option. So it is sufficient to be `trim=0 0 0 74, width=<desired width>`. If `trim` is needed, is impossible to judge, since your images is unknown.
- For series of consecutive pages is not needed set each page in `landscape` orientation  separately.

Possible MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \label{fig: Bolivia Politics 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth] {example-image-duck}
    \caption{Petroleum Sector in Bolivia under Evo Morales}
    \label{fig: Bolivia Petroleum}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]